# Regex to replace "/" by "OR"

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a code to replace `/` by `OR` (I am not particulary good with `regex`)

```
import re
def replace_or_symbol(summary=""):
    return re.sub("([A-Z])\/(?=[A-Z])", " OR ", summary)


print(replace_or_symbol(summary="AND/NOT AND"))
print(replace_or_symbol(summary="AND//NOT AND"))
```

It prints the output:

```
AN OR NOT AND
AND//NOT AND
```

In the output, `D` is missing in `AND`.

**Question**: How can i modify the code that can leave out the `D` in the `AND`?

**Note**: `//` Should not be replaced with `OR`

Comment: The `pattern` and `by` parameters are entirely pointless…?!

Comment: The actual operational regex here is `([A-Z])\/(?=[A-Z])`, which yes, will also match the `D` and won't match the `//`. If you'd use your `pattern` regex instead it should work as expected.

Comment: give a little more context and examples. Could there be  some spaces arounf the slahes?

Comment: @deceze, I have edited the question by removing the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the first capturing group `\\1 OR` in the replacement because this part `([A-Z])` captures the uppercase char.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zg78iK/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9CK1VD)

```
import re

def replace_or_symbol(summary=""):
    return re.sub("([A-Z])\/(?=[A-Z])", "\\1 OR ", summary)


print(replace_or_symbol(summary="AND/NOT AND"))
print(replace_or_symbol(summary="AND//NOT AND"))
```

Output

```
AND OR NOT AND
AND//NOT AND
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `([A-Z])\/(?=[A-Z])` matches an alphabet and '\'

you need add that as lookbehind
`(?<=[A-Z])\/(?=[A-Z])`

if more than one '/' also need to be replaced, following pattern can be used:

`(?<=[A-Z])\/+(?=[A-Z])`

'+' -- to match one or more '/'

Answer (score -1):

This should do the work

```
(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)
```

demo
https://regex101.com/r/WESubF/2

And replace with " OR "

Comment: I haven't down voted and also, your answer doesn't solve the problem. It captures both `/` and `//` where I only need `/` to be replaced.

Comment: But why you made then the double slash in the example? Please be clear in your questions

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it to explicitly stress that `//` should not be replaced.

Comment: Do you want to avoid changin if there are souble qouetes? Or you want convert one of them to OR? or maybe both? We need to know your specifications.

Comment: No you did not in the question itself. I see now it in the comments. But dont expect that everybody will read all the comments. Your FULL question should be in the Problem statement itself

Comment: Its understood by the other two users and its already answered. Thanks for your effort. I have edited the question to help others understand in future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209063/discussion-between-predicate-and-kartheek-palepu).